How to convert file in SCORM 1.2 fomrat to SCORM 2004 format without sourcefiles?
Our organization is in the process of migrating to new LMS which allows only SCORM 2004 format to be uploaded. But all our files are in SCORM 1.2 format in the old LMS. Some of the files are 2 to 3 years old that we are unable to track the actual source files. We have the SCORM 1.2 files downloaded from our old LMS. Is there a way to convert these files from SCORM 1.2 to SCORM 2004? Please advise.

Is there a scormdriver.js in the file list for the existing packages?

Yes, I can see a file with that name. Will that help us? Please advise.

In theory packages built with the Rustici Driver (scormdriver.js) (a product from Rustici Software who I work for) can be changed to work with a new standard just by switching a configuration value and/or by using a different manifest file. Depending on the version and configuration, the package should auto detect running in a SCORM 2004 player when launched in that way. If you need assistance in creating a SCORM 2004 imsmanifest.xml and/or want further help I'd recommend sending a message to support@scorm.com and referencing this post.

Thanks for your inputs. Wanted to check with you on the following doubt before sending message to the mail id that you shared. Though our package has scormdriver.js, it was not built with Rustici software. It was built using Articulate Storyline. Would Rustici software be able to help us even in this case?

Articulate (and other companies) license SCORM Driver from Rustici Software

@Vidya yes, most likely. As pipwerks mentioned the authoring tool is just outputting the package with the library inside, but the library itself is designed to handle multiple learning standards through the same interface, so it could very well work. Our folks will know how to transition the manifest and will likely point you to testing it in SCORM Cloud.

Thank you both for the information. This is a great news for us. Will reach out to my organization and take the next steps.
